# p:growl does not show global faces message

Tags: jsf, primefaces, growl

I've the below command button and growl component:

```
<p:commandButton id="reservationAdd" actionListener=" {reservationBean.addReservation()}" value="Dodaj" oncomplete="PF('wdlgAddReservation').hide();"  update=":frm" action="#{linkedTimelinesController.createTimeline()}"> 
    <f:ajax execute="reservationAdd" onevent="click" listener="#{messageControler.eventAdded()}"  render="dynamic"/>
</p:commandButton>

<p:growl id="msj" autoUpdate="true"/>
```

I'm adding a faces message as below:

```
@ManagedBean
public class MessageControler {

    public void eventAdded(){  
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Rezerwacja została dodana",null));  
    }
}
```

However, it does not show up in the growl component. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: There are a lot of ajax requests there - `action`, `actionListener`, and the `ajax` call on `click`. I suspect that the message is being cleared by one of those requests.

Comment: I see your `actionListener` is also missing `#`?

Answer (score 2):

My following minimal example works, perhaps you check the attributes of your `commandButton`

## page.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view>
        <h:head/>
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton value="Growl">
                    <f:ajax listener="#{page.triggerEvent}"/>
                </p:commandButton>

                <p:growl autoUpdate="true"/>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

## Page

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
public class Page {

    public void triggerEvent() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Test!", null));
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed code for tests to:                                                                 <p:commandButton id="test" value="test"> 
                    <f:ajax listener="#{messageControler.eventAdded}"/>
                </p:commandButton>                                                           After detailed tests, I noticed that the message appears but after double mouse click. How to change it to one click, on JAVA SWING it is acction mouse pressed. But I do not know how to change it in jsf.

Comment: You could move the event trigger to the `action` of the `p:commandButton` instead of an explicit `f:ajax` event as a `p:commandButton` uses AJAX implicitly.

Comment: Yes but I use: actionListener="#{reservationBean.addReservation()}" and action="#{linkedTimelinesController.createTimeline()}"  and I need this actions.

Comment: Why do you need several actions? Just combine them in one, do not infer any running order and de-obfuscate your code.

Comment: You're right, but this is my first aplication in jsf and my knowledge is still small. How to do that? Something like this: <h:commandButton value="Action">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{viewScopedBean.action}"/>
    <f:actionListener binding="#{sessionScopedBean.action}"/>
</h:commandButton />

Comment: Merge your code into *one* action and call it from the command button.

Comment: I created it in that way, tahanks for help. <p:commandButton  styleClass="button" id="add" value="Dodaj" oncomplete="PF('wdlgModyfikuj').hide();" ajax="false">
                                <f:actionListener binding="#{resourceBean.addResource()}"/> 
                                <f:actionListener binding="#{messageControler.eventAdded()}" />   
                            </p:commandButton>