# Primefaces messages doesn't get displayed (neither growl message)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wildfly, java-ee-7

I have a form which must be completed before user can proceed. Therefore the button is disabled until every field is correctly filled out. In order to help the user I want to display message when a field (for example email address) is not filled out correctly.
The problem is the message is not displayed. I tried using Primefaces' message, messages, growl without any result. I also tried to use javax Validation constraints and the logs said that message was fired but it wasn't displayed.
The page is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputLabel value="Test registration"/>
    <h:form id="registration-form">
        <p:growl showDetail="true"/>
        <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="3">
            <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Your Name: "/>
            <p:inputText id="name-input" value="#{testBean.name}" label="Name">
                <p:ajax update="save" event="blur" listener="#{testBean.validateName}"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:messages id="name-input-message" for="@previous" showDetail="true">
            </p:messages>

            <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Email: "/>
            <p:inputText id="email-input" value="#{testBean.email}" label="Email">
                <p:ajax update="save" event="blur" listener="#{testBean.validateEmail}"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:messages id="email-input-message" for="@previous" showDetail="true"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Password: "/>
            <p:inputText id="password-1-input" value="#{testBean.password1}" label="Password1">
                <p:ajax update="save" event="blur" listener="#{testBean.checkPasswords}"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:messages id="password-1-message" for="@previous" showDetail="true"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Password again: "/>
            <p:inputText id="password-2-input" value="#{testBean.password2}" label="Password2">
                <p:ajax update="save" event="keyup" listener="#{testBean.checkPasswords}"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:messages id="password-2-message" for="@previous" showDetail="true"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton id="save" value="Save" disabled="#{testBean.shouldBeDisabled}" icon="fa fa-save">
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And the bean is:

```
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password1;
    private String password2;

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    // .. getters, setters


    public Boolean getShouldBeDisabled() {
        return !(isNameValid() && isEmailValid() && arePasswordsEqual());
    }

    private boolean arePasswordsEqual() {
        if (password1 == null || password2 == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return password1.equals(password2);
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid() {
        boolean result = false;     
        if (email == null || email.isEmpty()) return result;
        try {
            InternetAddress address = InternetAddress.parse(email, true)[0];
            address.validate();
            result = true;
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            logger.debug("email is not valid");
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean isNameValid() {
        return !(name == null || name.isEmpty()) && name.length() > 1 && name.length() <= 60;
    }

    public void validateName() {
        if (!isNameValid()) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,"invalid","name is not valid"));
        }
    }

    public void validateEmail(){
        if(!isEmailValid()){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,"invalid","email is not valid"));
        }
    }

    public void checkPasswords(){
        if(!arePasswordsEqual())
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,"invalid","passwords must be equal"));
    }
}
```

And the loggers message:

```
FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-148) Adding Message[sourceId=<<NONE>>,summary=invalid)
```

To summarize: the message event is fired but the page is not updated.
What should I change to message get displayed either in message or growl?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you actually saying using a plain `h:message`, it IS shown? And when using a different java-ee-7 server it works too? Or when using a wildfly java-ee-8 compatible server it works too?

Comment: Off-topic: Being dependend on `import org.jboss.logging.Logger;` is not the best design

Comment: and <p:messages id="password-2-message" for="@previous" showDetail="true"/>
` is a strange usage of  `p:messages` A 'simple/singular' `p:message` makes more sense here

Comment: I also tried with h:message without any result.

Comment: And also tried with all plain jsf inputs? Making things a [mcve] (narrowing things down, back to see if plain jsf works)... and less fields and ....

Comment: Tried without the `@next` and `@previous`...?

Comment: First I tried p:ajax with updated outputText and it worked. Then I wanted to change outputText to message. I tried message for="idOfInputField" and later changed to @previous. I also tried to annotate name field with @Size(min=2, max=60) and the result was the same: logging message that message had been fired but the message wasn't displayed.

Comment: Please read (and respond to) the rest of my first comment. It is relevant to correct the tagging (most likely 3 of the four tags are unrelated (besides you using them in the stack))

Comment: And if you have created a [mcve] (no inputs outputexts or labels or groups or.. just a `p:growl` `h:form` `p:commandButton` (a plain jsf one with `h:messages`, `h:form` and  `h:commandButton` with `f:ajax` will suffice too), then try comparing the primefaces version with the PrimeFaces showcase or make the jsf version more simple by removing the f:ajax... Any change? THAT is creating an [mcve]. Something that should for the (in the end) obvious reason always be done

Comment: oh and the error you get about the message being added but not displayed makes a great search engine query... (adding 'jsf site:stackoverflow.com' helps a little to narrow the results a little more down)

Comment: As @Kukeltje suggested I made a minimal reproducible example with only one textfield, and I realized that for updating 'p:messages' field I should've to update it in p:ajax, too. So the right code is: <p:inputText id="email-input" value="#{testBean.email}" label="Email">
                <p:ajax update="save,email-input-message" event="blur" listener="#{testBean.validateEmail}"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:messages id="email-input-message" for="@previous" showDetail="true"/> Thank you Kukeltje!

Comment: Cheers and sorry for not telling you this directly. The approach you now took with the [mcve] is always, always, always helpful. It is the first thing I do when something does not work and you often generalize the problem then and find a generic solution. Please create an answer, with the [mcve] in it and the solution.  Can be a nice example Q/A for referring people to 'mcve'. Cheers

Comment: you tried the `global` attribute or the `autoupdate` for growl? see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093254/pgrowl-does-not-show-global-faces-message)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [p:growl does not show global faces message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093254/pgrowl-does-not-show-global-faces-message)

Comment: what I said in my last comment was only for the `growl`. If you want to show the messages when the button was clicked then add `update="@form"` to the commandbutton. just write if this solves your problem then i can add an answer with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue is you are not updating the p:messages

Try something like this:

```
<p:inputText id="name-input" value="#{testBean.name}" label="Name">
        <p:ajax update="save name-input-message" event="blur" listener="#{testBean.validateName}"/>
        </p:inputText>
<p:messages id="name-input-message" for="@previous" showDetail="true"/>
```

So, always update either the entire form as `update="@form"` or update the individual component using their IDs